# jquery div hide not working on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I  am using remote javascripts to populate two divs on my site.

```
<div id="flix-inpage"></div>

<div id="ccs-inline-content"></div>
```

i am using the following code  to display only one div if content is available on both divs. I have added this code to the bottom of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#flix-inpage #inpage_responsive").length > 0) {
            $("#ccs-inline-content").hide();
        } else {
            $("#ccs-inline-content").show();
            return false;
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

I have specified a  css  class:

```
#ccs-inline-content{
    display: none;
}
```

**If  Both DIV have same content**

The problem I am having is that `#ccs-inline-content` is  not hiding on first load. If I reload the page couple of times then `#ccs-inline-content` - `hide()` kicks in otherwise the content is visible.

I have tried different browser but same result.

Comment: try removing the setTimeout

Comment: setTimeout is only executed once, in your case after 2 seconds. Does it take longer than that for the div to be populated? If so you may want to consider setInterval instead which will run the function repeatedly on an interval. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Its hiding instantly for me - due to CSS not JQuery(because this kicks in after 2 secs due to `setTimeout`). Check this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/QGOmMY)

Comment: @ C. Smith setInterval did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i test this code , but good working . just i add .text() function in this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#flix-inpage").text().length <= 0 ) {
             $("#ccs-inline-content").show();
        } else {
             $("#ccs-inline-content").hide();
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#ccs-inline-content{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="flix-inpage">12</div>

<div id="ccs-inline-content">ok</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `#flix-inpage` to be shown and `#ccs-inline-content` to be hidden unless `#flix-inpage` is empty. This would do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#flix-inpage").children().length) {
    $("#ccs-inline-content").hide();
  } else {
    $("#ccs-inline-content").show();
  }
});
```

You need to make sure the other scripts you mentioned finish before this runs, So put this somewhere after you execute the other two, at the bottom of the `<body>` tag.